# Mutli-level index using only certain values from 2 columns

Tags: pandas, multi-index

Good morning!
I am very new to pandas/python. I mainly use SQL and SSIS for my current ETL, but for a new data source it requires tedious manual reformatting in excel. I am trying to learn python to save hours of manual work. The data on the report is extremely redundant. I have spent days trying to phrase  what I need in a way that returns the information I need, but to no avail.

I can't use my actual data because it contains PHI, so I will give an analogous example using Clients and Orders. An external system generates a 'MonthlyOrders.xls' report. There is pretty much ZERO flexibility in the export format. The .xls file extension gives you an idea about how dated the source environment is. First, I loaded the data to a data frame and split it down into smaller data frames by "Group". So each df represents one group. This is what it looks like after that:

General Format:

| index | Name/Date | ID/Item | Price/ 'P' | Billed/'NaaN' | PaidOn/Seller | Total/Dept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ClientName | Client ID | 'P' | Date Billed | Pmt_received_On | Order Total |
| 2 | Order Date | item name | item price | 'NaaN' | sold by | dept |
| 3 | Same order date | 2nd item | price | 'Naan' | sold by | dept |
| 4 | NextClientName | NextID | 'P' | Date Billed | Pmt_received_On | Order Total |

Example of Data:

| Index | Name/Date | ID/Item | Price/ 'P' | Billed/'NaaN' | PaidOn/Seller | Total/Dept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Victim, One | VO100 | 'P' | 08/12/2021 | 08/13/2021 | 78 |
| 2 | 08/11/2021 | books | 12 | 'NaaN' | Mrs. White | The Study |
| 3 | 08/11/2021 | Rope | 56 | 'Naan' | Mrs. White | The Study |
| 4 | 08/11/2021 | Pens | 10 | 'NaaN' | Mrs. White | The Study |
| 5 | Second, Dead | SD123 | 'P' | 08/18/2021 | 08/20/2021 | 250 |
| 6 | 08/17/2021 | Pool Cue | 198 | 'NaaN' | Mr. Green | Billiard Room |
| 7 | 08/17/2021 | Knife | 52 | 'Naan' | Mr. Green | Billiard Room |

What I want to do is create a multi-level index using Client Name and Client ID, OrderDate.
Maybe could I put the Name:ID as a dictionary and use that as the first level of index and then the date would be the next level. I am not sure if I can do that.

Or, I want to split the first and second columns into four columns (Name, ID, orderDate, Item). I do not use the 'Order Total' column. The data goes into a Billing_Import staging table, and then I is further manipulated and transformed in the Data Warehouse. The destination table has the following structure:

| RecID | Group | ClientName | OrderDate | ClientID | ItemID | desc | ChgAmt | pmtAmt | seller | dept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

The 'RecID' is added in SSIS, and 'Item ID' split from the 'Desc' column after import with SQL. I plan to add a "Group" column back into each data frame so I know which data belongs to which group. Right now the groups are in separate data frames.

The 'Department' will always be the same for an order. There almost always only one 'Seller', but if there were 2 sellers on one order another record would be added.

The format I want would look like this:

| Group | ID | Name | OrderDate | ItemDesc | Charge | Pmt | Seller | Department |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | ID1a | Name1a | 1/1/2021 | item1 | $x | $y | Ms. Scarlet | The Lounge |
|  |  |  |  | item2 | $x | $y | Ms. Scarlet |  |
|  |  |  |  | item3 | $x | $y | Ms. Scarlet |  |
|  | ID2a | Name2b | 1/15/2021 | item1 | $x | $y | Mrs. Peacock | The Kitchen |
|  |  |  |  | item2 | $x | $y | Mrs. Peacock |  |
| Group2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | ID2a | Name2a | 1/22/2021 | item1 | $x | $y | Wadsworth | The Cellar |
|  |  |  |  | item2 | $x | $y | Wadsworth |  |
|  | ID2a | Name2a | 1/22/2021 | item1 | $x | $y | Col. Mustard | The Cellar |

Any and all suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Kindest Regards,

Cori

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to separate columns into a format similar to:

| index | name | date | ID | item | price | billed | paid_on | seller | total | dept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 10/20/21 | 1234 | socks | 10 | 10/12/21 | 10/20/21 | James | 10 | garments |

Once this step is complete, you can create your Multi-Index with:

```
df_muti_index = df.set_index(['ID', 'name', 'date'])
```

Comment: The issue is that the Name and ID are only in the first row, then the subsequent x rows have the order details.  From the example data:

Comment: The issue is that the Customer ID is  only in the first row, so I need to attach that ID to the subsequent x rows  below it.  From my example, Index Rows 1-4 rows are all one order, but lines 2-4 aren't tied to the customer's ID. I need it to be formatted:      | ID | Name | date | item1 | price1 | item2 | price2 | item3 | price3 | seller | department |  |VO100 | Victim, One | 08/11/2021| books | 12 | rope | 56 | pens |10 |Mrs. White | The study | The order details are only listed below the customer, and not tied to anyone. Does that make sense?